# DateTime format VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a text file, which i had extracted the date and time. I need it to be this way

> yyyy MM dd HH mm

how can i make it into this format.

I tried

```
dim date as DateTime = line.Substring(line.Length - 19, 16)
date= DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy MM dd HH mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

it gave an error

Comment: Pass a string as the 1st argument to ParseExact, not a date.  Put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file so the compiler will tell you about mistakes like this.

Comment: You can check this http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/date-time-functions-visual-basic

Comment: In the future, I recommend specifying the exact error you receive

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN, [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) has 3 parameters:

```
s
Type: System.String
A string that contains a date and time to convert.

format
Type: System.String
A format specifier that defines the required format of s.
For more information, see the Remarks section.

provider
Type: System.IFormatProvider
An object that supplies culture-specific format information about s.
```

So it needs to be something like this instead:

```
Dim [date] as DateTime =DateTime.ParseExact(line.Substring(line.Length - 19, 16),
                        "yyyy MM dd HH mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Notice that date here will be reported as a non-valid identifier, so you need square braces. A better solution would be to give a meaningful name to your variable. Unfortunately, I cannot suggest one, because you did not provide any context in your question.